# SQL Report Builder for Survey Data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a large dataset with People's names and their Rating from 1 to 5.
Then I made a query that summarizes this data for PersonA:

```
Rating   Count
-------  ------
 1        4
 2        6
 3        1
 4        0
 5        2
```

I just need to know how to show this on my report.
I have made a cell for each rating and need to put in an expression that says "If Rating=1, show count for rating 1".

I tried using `=IIf(Fields!Rating.Value = 1, Fields!Count.Value, 0)` but this didn't work.

Comment: From looking at the answer & comments below it is clear that I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. What exactly does your dataset(s) look like? What layout are you trying to get in the report? If your dataset only summarizes the information for Person A how do you plan on showing Person B's info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need an expression like that, based on your description of the dataset it sounds like you already have two columns of data for rating and count, so you could use a tablix (table), with columns:

```
Rating   Count
```

which would list all the rating values and associated count values, similar to the example result in your question.

Comment: This works, but I need to move the the rating values around, so they will be in 5 different tables, not a single table.  For example, I would put a sentence "PersonA has <count> counts of rating <rating>."  The issue with my report is that not everything line is supposed to line up.

Comment: If you are wanting to use the dataset values in something that isn't a data region e.g. a text box, then you can use the Lookup() function to return a specifc value from a row in the dataset, e.g. to look up the count for rating "1"..  =Lookup("1", Fields!Rating.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "MyDataset"), or if Rating is a integer... =Lookup(CInt(1), Fields!Rating.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "MyDataset")

Comment: `=Lookup("1", Fields!Rating.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "MyDataset")` was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!!!